# Finding three formulas such that they are consistent as pairs, but inconsistent when all three are together.

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

This problem and several others of a similar nature have shown up in my textbook in introductory logic:

"Give formulas $\phi, \psi, \sigma$ such that any pairing of them defines a consistent theory, but not all three together."

I know that, by definition, a theory $\Gamma$ is consistent if one cannot derive $\bot$ from $\Gamma$, using the rules of natural deduction. However, I'm not quite sure where to start. So far, we have only dealt with propositional logic. Is there a straight-forward way to handle these sorts of problems, using the syntax of propositional logic?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The way to handle this problem is to write down an ingenious choice of $\phi, \psi, \sigma$, and then do some fairly routine checks to see they work. Maybe it helps to rephrase this question as "find a minimal inconsistent theory of cardinality $3$" - IE you are looking for an inconsistent theory where the derivation of $\bot$ uses all hypotheses in an essential way. (CF: find three integers, pairwise not coprime, that are mutually coprime). Try writing down some inconsistent theories and playing around with how you could need three propositions to prove $\bot$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you for the comment! I guess my question was more about how to tackle these sorts of problems without excessive "guesswork". I do know of some inconsistent theories so I guess I'll start with those.

Comment: I see! I don't think there is a uniform systematic way to approach problems like this, really. I think the point is to gain some intuition about consistency and entailment by playing around a bit and getting your hands on some examples. I wouldn't say that's necessarily guesswork, though - I'd describe it as "doing mathematics". For me this specific type of problem about a minimal object of size 3 always strongly evokes the "coprime" example, and the idea of the solution tends to be sort of similar.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Great, thank you! As a final question: do you know of any useful resources where one can find examples of common consistent/inconsistent theories? Our textbook is pretty poor at giving examples in this area, and my search on the web comes up empty. Perhaps you have a preferred textbook yourself in introductory logic? :)

Comment: [These](https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/ii/Logic_and_Set_Theory.pdf) are the lecture notes for the course where I learned it, with some recommended books (which I can't personally vouch for). I think the key facts are that if a theory proves $p$ and $\lnot p$ for some $p$, it's inconsistent, but if it has a model, it's consistent. If the elements of the theory are suitably "independent", it's probably consistent, but if they interact to do something weird, it can be inconsistent. EG $\{p_1, p_2, p_3\}$, $\{p_1 \implies p_2, p_2\}$ are consistent, $\{(p_1 \land p_2), \lnot p_1\}$ isn't.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Fantastic, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: One possibility that came to mind: $\{ p \leftrightarrow q, q \leftrightarrow r, r \leftrightarrow (\lnot p) \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set of formulas is consistent if and only if there is a valuation for all of the formulas in the set to be true together.

Consider the formulas $\phi_{1}$, $\phi_{2}$ and $\phi_{3}$. We take $\phi_{3}$ as $$\phi_{1}\rightarrow\neg\phi_{2}$$

Then, the set $\{\phi_{1}, \phi_{1}\rightarrow\neg\phi_{2}\}$, hence, $\{\phi_{1}, \phi_{3}\}$ is consistent, for $\phi_{1}$ is true and $\phi_{2}$ is false. Notice that $\phi_{2}$ occurs in the compound formula $\phi_{3}$, but not in the set; compare this case to that of a set $A$ defined as $\{a, \{b\}\}$ for which $b\notin A$.

Likewise, $\{\phi_{1}, \phi_{2}\}$ and $\{\phi_{2}, \phi_{3}\}$ are consistent sets, but $\{\phi_{1}, \phi_{2}, \phi_{3}\}$ is not.

Consider now four formulas, $\phi_{1}$, $\phi_{2}$, $\phi_{3}$ and $\phi_{4}$. Take $\phi_{4}$ as $$\phi_{1}\rightarrow\neg\phi_{2}\vee\phi_{2}\rightarrow\neg\phi_{3}\vee\phi_{3}\rightarrow\neg\phi_{1}$$

If, as above, we evaluate the formula(s) left out to false, we get consistent sets of two and three formulas, but not of four formulas; $\{\phi_{1}, \phi_{2}, \phi_{3}, \phi_{4}\}$ is not consistent.

Following this pattern, we can inductively construct larger sets in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, in a language with two unary predicates $P, Q$, the following sentences :

- $\phi$ states that there are precisely two elements that satisfy $P$.
- $\psi$ states that there are precisely two elements that satisfy $Q$.
- $\sigma$ states that there are precisely three elements in total, and that $P$ and $Q$ are disoint.